# The time data does not match format

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, datetime

Hello I am trying to convert a string which is `a = "2019-04-22 00:00"` to a datetime but it does not work, I tried this :

```
a = datetime.datetime.strptime(a, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
```

But I got

> time data 'start_period' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M'

I precise `start_period` is get by this : `a = request.POST.get('start_period')`

Comment: Hello, can you please also share your code ? I tried your example and it worked for me.

Comment: Are you 100% sure that the string is exactly `"2019-04-22 00:00"`? Maybe there are some invisible non-printable characters. What does it display if you do `print(repr(a))` before calling strptime?

Comment: Looks like you have used quotes around the variable EX: -->`datetime.datetime.strptime("start_period", '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')` Remove them and it should work

Comment: You did notice that your string variable and the method (strptime) are named 'a'

Answer (score 1):

Like this it should work:

```
import datetime
start_period = "2019-04-22 00:00"
a = datetime.datetime.strptime(start_period, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
```

Result:

```
datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 22, 0, 0)
```

Comment: Besides the import statement, isn't this just exactly the code that the OP had in his post? While it is a useful observation to say "actually your code works fine on my machine", that's traditionally done as a comment and not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest using [dateutil](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) module, where you do not need to provide the format string

```
from dateutil import parser

print(parser.parse("2019-04-22 00:00"))
#2019-04-22 00:00:00
```

Answer (score 0):

there are multiple ways to convert string to datetime in python. it is based on the requirement of the user which function to use.

one possible solution could be as given below.

```
import timestring
start_period = "2019-04-22 00:00"
print(timestring.Date(start_period))
```